# The number of non normal subgroups of a group cannot be $1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $n$ be the number of subgroups of $G$ that are not normal. Prove that $n\not=1$.

---

When $G$ is Abelian, then this is trivial since $n=0$. For the non-Abelian group $G$, I have to show that $n\geq 2$. But I don't see how to go on. Any hint?

Comment: Notice that $n=0$ can happen even if $G$ is non-abelian (for example take the Quaterion group).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is called normal if $g^{-1} N g = N$ for all $g \in G$.  So suppose $N$ isn't normal.  What is $g^{-1} N g$ if $g^{-1} N g \ne N$?

Comment: Ah, so the point is starting from any non normal subgroup, one can give another non normal subgroup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check out this [paper](https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/handle/1887/3830). Here all groups $G$ are classified that have only finitely many non-normal subgroups. It is proved that a group $G$ has this property if and only if it is either *abelian*, or *Hamiltonian*, or *finite*, or of the *form* $A \times B$, where $A$ and $B$ are as follows: $B$ contains
for some prime number $p$, a central subgroup $C$ that is isomorphic to the group of
complex roots of unity of $p$-power order, such that $B/C$ is a finite abelian $p$-group, and $A$ is a finite abelian or Hamiltonian group of order not divisible by $p$.

It follows from
this result that any infinite group that has non-normal subgroups at all has at least
six of them, with equality occurring for precisely one group, up to isomorphism.